# file_get_html not working? while other files are working smoothly

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

i have a html file that opens fine on broswer but when i try to open it through file_get_html it show no object found.

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html= file_get_html('opodos.html');

echo $html->plaintext;
```

[image]

kindly guide me through if iam missing something related to this and yes onemore thing i am using this in localhost.

Comment: Is this a local file?

Comment: You probably need a full url, e.g. `file_get_html('http://some.server/path/opodos.html');`

Comment: Do a `var_dump` to see what is `$html` like. If it's `bool(false)` then it may be a too large file. Try setting `define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 6000000);` before including simple_html_dom...

Comment: `file_get_html()` returns `false` if it gets an error. You need to check for that before using it as an object.

Comment: @user1 yes its a local file

Comment: @FranzTesca yup you are right Thanks for your help :)